# Grouping points by certain rules

Tags: gis

I need to group point data, that I plotted out. 
I have a points with the attributes "A", "Slots#", "w".

I need to Group within "A" the "W" in to groups "slots#" that are within 1000 meters of each other.

Im not sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated.